# if we have a subspace of $V$ and that is $W$, if we span it, do we get $W$ itself ??

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Hey guys I just have this issue  and I hope that  you can just help me with  as possible

when $W$ is a subspace of $V$, $\operatorname{span}(W) = W$.

This is always true, right ??

Comment: Welcome toMaths SX! It is obvious since by definition, $\operatorname{span}(W)$ is the smallest subspace containing $W$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different but equivalent ways to define the span of a set of vectors.  One is to say that the span is the set of all linear combinations of vectors in the set.  The other definition is to define the span to be the intersection of all the subspaces that contain the vectors in the set.  The second definition amounts to saying that the span of $W$ is the *smallest* subspace which contains $W$.  As $W$ is itself a subspace you can see intuitively that it must then be the smallest because anything smaller than $W$ doesn't contain all of $W$.  Thus $\mathrm{span} \ W = W$ whenever $W$ is a subspace.

After you accept intuitively that this is true I highly recommend you take your definition of choice and try to prove this fact formally, it's a good exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You are correct. Spanning means you are just using the operations of the vector space on the elements of the subspace. The resulting elements should be there in the subspace since it inherits all the properties of  vector space.

Answer (score 0):

Go back all the way to the beginning, to the vector space axioms. One of them is that the space is closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication. Since $W$ is a vector space, this means that every linear combination of elements of $W$ lies in $W$, but that’s exactly the definition of the span of the set $W$.